# Display only one Shell if the shell if previously open not display another shell

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, balloon

I am developing a rcp application .I am using a Novocode swt balloon window . I need to display one BaloonWindow on button click.but whenever I click on button each time create a new balloon window

My code is below

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    try {
        BalloonWindow baloonWindow=new BalloonWindow(HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getShell(),SWT.ON_TOP|SWT.TOOL|SWT.CLOSE);
        baloonWindow.setText("XYZ");            
        baloonWindow.setAnchor(SWT.RIGHT|SWT.TOP);
        baloonWindow.setLocation(1290, 90);
        Composite c = baloonWindow.getContents();
        String array[]=new String[2];               
        array[0]="A";
        array[1]="B";                       
        c.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        TableViewer t=new TableViewer(c,SWT.NONE);
        t.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        t.setInput(array);
        c.pack(true);   
        baloonWindow.setVisible(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

anybody can help me.how to show only one balloon window at time.if a balloon window is open then another balloon window should not be allowed to open or there should remain only one balloon window open at any given point of time.

Comment: I don't know anything about the technology you are using, but I see in your code that you don't hide any previous "baloon" windows when you are creating a new one.

Comment: that's what i  want to do. I have only one balloon. on every button click a new balloon is opened, so it creates a stack of balloons.I could not find any method to hide balloon for eg `hideBalloon()`

Comment: Something like "setVisible(false)" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understood you ultimate goal, so here are two possibilities:

---

**First** (at most one `BalloonWindow` at a time)

Create a `static` `boolean` field `isOpen` in your class containing the `execute()` method. Set this variable to `true` once you created the `BalloonWindow` and check this variable each time you enter `execute()`. If it is `false`, create a new `BalloonWindow`, if it is `true`, `return`.

---

**Second** (close the `BalloonWindow`)

The `BalloonWindow` has a method `open()`. Use this method to open it instead of `setVisible(true)`. If you want to close the `BalloonWindow`, just call `close()`. `setVisible(false)` would have the same visual effect (the window is gone), but it would still be there (only invisible). `close` really closes the window.

Comment: i want to display a ballonwindow at a time if any other baloon window is open its does not create another ballonwindow .if no any one baloon window is open then create or open new baloonwindow

Comment: @Abhit Then use the first possibility.

Comment: @Abhit Please accept and upvote this answer, if it solved you problem. If not, please clarify.